# Speeding up COUNT(*) - WHERE clause slowing query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

The following query takes 497 ms to run, if I remove the AND portion onwards it only takes 320 ms. Is there any way to speed this up? The only indexes I have on 'messages' table is a PK on 'messages_id'. The 'hidden' field is a bit field (not null) and 'message_type_id' is an int field (not null) and message_id is an int field (PK).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages
WHERE message_type_id = 1
AND (hidden = 0 OR message_id = @message_id)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this related to [your other question that you recently opened](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22379/1945)?

Comment: You might also not want to pass everything to the count function. Depending on the database that may not be optimal. It may grab everything, then count it. It might be easier to do just a count(message_type_id). Should give you the same result, but helps the engine to cut off extra rows it doesn't need to care about.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach to remove the OR.
You could try this and have 2 indexes on the table to satisfy the WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT message_id
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_type_id = 1 AND hidden = 0
    UNION
    SELECT message_id
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_type_id = 1 AND message_id = @message_id
    ) X
```

Comment: I assume you mean `SELECT message_id`? (Borderline was going to edit this myself.)

Comment: @JonSeigel: makes no difference unless message_id is NULLable

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant the `SELECT`s in the derived table.

Comment: @JonSeigel: again, no. The COUNT does not have DISTINCT. So it all comes down to nullability of message_type_id (which won't be NULL because of the WHERE). We could use the constant 1 too.

Comment: Right, but the `UNION` will discard duplicates, giving an overall `COUNT` of either 0 or 1, always. So either the `SELECT`ed field needs to be unique for the rows, or the derived table needs `UNION ALL` instead. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: @JonSeigel: oh bloody hell yes. will correct

Comment: Actually, on second thought, `UNION ALL` doesn't work because of the possible intersection. Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a covering index on the following columns (message_type_id, hidden, message_id). Try out different order of columns in the index: that might make some difference.

I would rather not use a filtered index: it is quite likely that the optimizer would fail to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did nothing for the query time

Comment: And you were right, the filtered index wasn't used by the optimizer

Answer (score 4):

Because of the `OR` predicate, the best you'll be able to do for this query is get an index scan plan. I'm assuming you're seeing a table scan right now. Depending on how wide the base table is, this may or may not make a big difference in the execution time.

Assuming the primary key index is clustered, create an index on `message_type_id` with the `hidden` column `INCLUDE`d. (The primary key column as the clustering key will be included in the index automatically.)

If you're only ever searching the table for `message_type_id` = 1, you could filter the index to only capture those rows instead of all the table rows.

Answer (score 3):

A filtered index might help:

```
CREATE INDEX f_idx_1 
  ON dbo.messages(message_type_id, message_id, hidden) 
  WHERE message_type_id = 1;
```

Comment: It might or might not help: I've been burned a few times by the optimizer that ignores filtered indexes.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov yep, I said *might* for a reason.

Comment: That said, I have found them to be relatively more reliable on modern builds than when the feature was first introduced.

Comment: IIRC, SQL Server uses filtered indexes better if the filter to by is in the column list. So `CREATE INDEX f_idx_1 ON dbo.messages( message_type_id, message_id, hidden) WHERE message_type_id = 1`. Yeah, some good stuff here on that http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx#Restrictions